# Best way to copy a date field to datetime?

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, casting

What is the best way to copy a date field to a datetime field using mysql?

I need to take the date from the date column and copy it over to the datetime field with a generic hour:min:00.000.

```
 Ex:  2017-04-04 to 2017-04-04 11:05:57.000 (actual time does not matter)
```

Any ideas on the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 CAST(date_column AS DATETIME)
```

But you really don't need to do anything special. When a  `DATE` field is evaluated in a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` context, the server coerces the data automatically.